# When to dispose CancellationTokenSource?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, plinq, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

The class `CancellationTokenSource` is disposable. A quick look in Reflector proves usage of `KernelEvent`, a (very likely) unmanaged resource.
Since `CancellationTokenSource` has no finalizer, if we do not dispose it, the GC won't do it.

On the other hand, if you look at the samples listed on the MSDN article [Cancellation in Managed Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx), only one code snippet disposes of the token.

What is the proper way to dispose of it in code?

1. You cannot wrap code starting your parallel task with `using` if you do not wait for it. And it makes sense to have cancellation only if you do not wait.
2. Of course you can add `ContinueWith` on task with a `Dispose` call, but is that the way to go?
3. What about cancelable PLINQ queries, which do not synchronize back, but just do something at the end? Let's say `.ForAll(x => Console.Write(x))`?
4. Is it reusable? Can the same token be used for several calls and then dispose it together with the host component, let's say UI control?

Because it does not have something like a `Reset` method to clean-up `IsCancelRequested` and `Token` field I would suppose it's not reusable, thus every time you start a task (or a PLINQ query) you should create a new one. Is it true? If yes, my question is what is the correct and recommended strategy to deal with `Dispose` on those many `CancellationTokenSource` instances?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Speaking about whether it's really necessary to call Dispose on `CancellationTokenSource`... I had a memory leak in my project and it turned out that `CancellationTokenSource` was the problem.

My project has a service, that is constantly reading database and fires off different tasks, and I was passing linked cancellation tokens to my workers, so even after they had finished processing data, cancellation tokens weren't disposed, which caused a memory leak.

MSDN [Cancellation in Managed Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) states it clearly:

> Notice that you must call `Dispose` on the linked token source when you are done with it. For a more complete example, see [How to: Listen for Multiple Cancellation Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-listen-for-multiple-cancellation-requests).

I used `ContinueWith` in my implementation.

Comment: This is an important omission in the current accepted answer by Bryan Crosby - if you create a _linked_ CTS, you risk memory leaks. The scenario is very similar to event handlers that are never unregistered.

Comment: I had a leak due to this same issue. Using a profiler I could see callback registrations holding references to the linked CTS instances. Examining the code for the CTS Dispose implementation [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs,548) was very insightful, and underscores @SørenBoisen comparison to event handler registration leaks.

Comment: Comments above reflect the discussion state were the other answer by @Bryan Crosby was accepted.

Comment: The documentation in 2020 clearly says: `Important: The CancellationTokenSource class implements the IDisposable interface. You should be sure to call the CancellationTokenSource.Dispose method when you have finished using the cancellation token source to free any unmanaged resources it holds.` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 72):

I didn't think any of the current answers were satisfactory. After researching I found this reply from Stephen Toub ([reference](http://web.archive.org/web/20160203062224/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx)):

> It depends.
> In .NET 4, CTS.Dispose served two primary purposes.  If the
> CancellationToken's WaitHandle had been accessed (thus lazily
> allocating it), Dispose will dispose of that handle.  Additionally, if
> the CTS was created via the CreateLinkedTokenSource method, Dispose
> will unlink the CTS from the tokens it was linked to.  In .NET 4.5,
> Dispose has an additional purpose, which is if the CTS uses a Timer
> under the covers (e.g. CancelAfter was called), the Timer will be
> Disposed.
>
> It's very rare for CancellationToken.WaitHandle to be used,
> so cleaning up after it typically isn't a great reason to use Dispose.
> **If, however, you're creating your CTS with CreateLinkedTokenSource, or
> if you're using the CTS' timer functionality, it can be more impactful
> to use Dispose.**

The bold part I think is the important part. He uses "more impactful" which leaves it a bit vague. I'm interpreting it as meaning calling `Dispose` in those situations should be done, otherwise using `Dispose` is not needed.

Comment: More impactful means that child CTS is added to parent one. If you don't dispose child there will be a leak if parent is long-living. So it is critical to dispose linked ones.

Comment: And you never know when token you passed somewhere will be linked to

Comment: One more comment by Stephen Toub that [I just found](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29970#issuecomment-717840778 "CancellationTokenSource is hard to use correctly"): *"It's good to dispose of disposable things in general. But sometimes, especially when dealing with asynchronous code, or when dealing with code where ownership or lifetimes isn't clear, that such a general guideline needs to be weighed for its benefits / risks. With CTS, it's most important to Dispose of it when created with CreateLinkedTokenSource, and secondarily when it's used with a timeout."* dated Oct 28, 2020

Answer (score 32):

You should always dispose `CancellationTokenSource`.

How to dispose it depends exactly on the scenario.  You propose several different scenarios.

1. `using` only works when you're using `CancellationTokenSource` on some parallel work that you're waiting.  If that's your senario, then great, it's the easiest method.
2. When using tasks, use a `ContinueWith` task as you indicated to dispose of `CancellationTokenSource`.
3. For plinq you can use `using` since you're running it in parallel but waiting on all of the parallel running workers to finish.
4. For UI, you can create a new `CancellationTokenSource` for each cancellable operation that is not tied to a single cancel trigger.  Maintain a `List<IDisposable>` and add each source to the list, disposing all of them when your component is disposed.
5. For threads, create a new thread that joins all the worker threads and closes the single source when all of the worker threads finished.  See [CancellationTokenSource, When to dispose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443813/cancellationtokensource-when-to-dispose/18445515#18445515)

There's always a way.  `IDisposable` instances should always be disposed.  Samples often don't because they're either quick samples to show core usage or because adding in all aspects of the class being demonstrated would be overly complex for a sample.  The sample is just that a sample, not necessarily (or even usually) production quality code.  Not all samples are acceptable to be copied into production code as is.

Comment: for point 2, any reason you could not use `await` on the task and dispose the CancellationTokenSource in the code that comes after the await?

Comment: There are caveats.  If the CTS gets canceled while you `await` an operation, you may resume due to an `OperationCanceledException`.  You might then call `Dispose()`.  But if there are operations still running and using the corresponding `CancellationToken`, that token still reports `CanBeCanceled` as being `true` even though the source is disposed.  If they attempt to register a cancellation callback, **BOOM!**, `ObjectDisposedException`.  It's safe enough to call `Dispose()` after successful completion of the operation(s).  It gets *really tricky* when you actually need to cancel something.

Comment: Downvoted for the reasons given by Mike Strobel - forcing a rule to always call Dispose can get you into hairy situations when dealing with CTS and Task due to their asynchronous nature. The rule should instead be: always dispose _linked_ token sources.

Comment: Your link goes to a deleted answer.

Comment: For more on the conditions @MikeStrobel describes, see [this concise summary](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29970#issue-558467269) of the various CTS perils. Also, for the record, if such issues apply to your code base but you still insist on disposing every CTS, the neccessary approach/fix would be to manually unlink the registrations and detach any timers prior to disposing the CTS. Beware, though, you might be [in for it](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/Microsoft.Bcl/System.Threading.Tasks.v1.5/System/Threading/CancellationTokenRegistration.cs#L64).

Comment: There's also some good information in a [code comment](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs#L558-L571) from the latest .NET source of `CancellationTokenSource`.

Comment: @glenslayden thanks! Looks live the implementation of Dispose changed a lot since my original answer and it's even more important to call Dispose now.

Answer (score 30):

I took a look in ILSpy for the `CancellationTokenSource` but I can only find `m_KernelEvent` which is actually a `ManualResetEvent`, which is a wrapper class for a `WaitHandle` object. This should be handled properly by the GC.

Comment: I have the same feeling that GC will cleanup that all. I'll try to verify that. Why do Microsoft implemented dispose in this case? To get rid of event callbacks and avoid propagation to second generation GC probably. In this case calling Dispose is optional - call it if you can, if not just ignore it. Not the best manner I think.

Comment: I have investigated this issue. CancellationTokenSource gets garbage collected. You might help with dispose to do it in GEN 1 GC. Accepted.

Comment: I did this same investigation independently and came to the same conclusion: dispose if you easily can, but don't fret over trying to do so in the rare-but-not-unheard-of cases where you've sent a CancellationToken out into the boondocks and don't want to wait for them to write a postcard back telling you they're done with it.  This is going to happen every now and then because of the nature of what CancellationToken is used for, and it's really OK, I promise.

Comment: My above comment doesn't apply to linked token sources; I couldn't prove that it's OK to leave these undisposed, and the wisdom in this thread and MSDN suggests that it might not be.

Answer (score 27):

This answer is still coming up in Google searches, and I believe the voted up answer does not give the full story. After looking over the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs) for `CancellationTokenSource` (CTS) and `CancellationToken` (CT) I believe that for most use cases the following code sequence is fine:

```
if (cancelTokenSource != null)
{
    cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
    cancelTokenSource.Dispose();
    cancelTokenSource = null;
}
```

The `m_kernelHandle` internal field mentioned above is the synchronization object backing the `WaitHandle` property in both the CTS and CT classes.  It is only instantiated if you access that property.  So, unless you are using `WaitHandle` for some old-school thread synchronization in your `Task` calling dispose will have no effect.

Of course, if you *are* using it you should do what is suggested by the other answers above and delay calling `Dispose` until any `WaitHandle` operations using the handle are complete, because, as is described in the [Windows API documentation for WaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx), the results are undefined.

Comment: The MSDN article [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) states: "Listeners monitor the value of the `IsCancellationRequested` property of the token by polling, callback, or wait handle." In other words: It may not be _you_ (i.e. the one making the async request) who uses the wait handle, it may be the listener (i.e. the one answering the request). Which means you, as the one responsible for disposing, effectively have no control over whether the wait handle is used or not.

Comment: According to MSDN, registered callbacks that have exceptioned will cause .Cancel to throw. Your code will not call .Dispose() if this happens. The callbacks should be careful not to do this, but it can happen.

Answer (score 27):

It has been a long time since I asked this and got many helpful answers but I came across an interesting issue related to this and thought I would post it here as another answer of sorts:

You should call `CancellationTokenSource.Dispose()` only when you are sure that nobody is going to try to get the CTS's `Token` property. Otherwise you should *not* call `Dispose()`, because it creates a race condition. For instance, see here:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/108

In the fix for this issue, code which previously did `cts.Cancel(); cts.Dispose();` was edited to just do `cts.Cancel();` because anyone so unlucky as to try to get the cancellation token in order to observe its cancellation state *after* `Dispose` has been called will unfortunately also need to handle `ObjectDisposedException` - in addition to the `OperationCanceledException` that they were planning for.

Another key observation related to this fix is made by Tratcher: "Disposal is only required for tokens that won't be cancelled, as cancellation does all of the same cleanup."
i.e. just doing `Cancel()` instead of disposing is really good enough!

Answer (score 13):

I wrote a thread-safe class that binds a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource) to a `Task`, and guarantees that the `CancellationTokenSource` will be disposed when its associated `Task` completes. It uses locks to ensure that the `CancellationTokenSource` will not be canceled during or after it has been disposed. This happens for compliance with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource#thread-safety), that states:

> The `Dispose` method must only be used when all other operations on the `CancellationTokenSource` object have completed.

And [also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.dispose#remarks):

> The `Dispose` method leaves the `CancellationTokenSource` in an unusable state.

Here is the `CancelableExecution` class:

```
public class CancelableExecution
{
    private readonly bool _allowConcurrency;
    private Operation _activeOperation;

    // Represents a cancelable operation that signals its completion when disposed
    private class Operation : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;
        private readonly TaskCompletionSource _completionSource;
        private bool _disposed;

        public Task Completion => _completionSource.Task; // Never fails

        public Operation(CancellationTokenSource cts)
        {
            _cts = cts;
            _completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource(
                TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        }

        public void Cancel() { lock (this) if (!_disposed) _cts.Cancel(); }

        void IDisposable.Dispose() // It is disposed once and only once
        {
            try { lock (this) { _cts.Dispose(); _disposed = true; } }
            finally { _completionSource.SetResult(); }
        }
    }

    public CancelableExecution(bool allowConcurrency)
    {
        _allowConcurrency = allowConcurrency;
    }
    public CancelableExecution() : this(false) { }

    public bool IsRunning => Volatile.Read(ref _activeOperation) != null;

    public async Task<TResult> RunAsync<TResult>(
        Func<CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> action,
        CancellationToken extraToken = default)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(action);
        CancellationTokenSource cts = CancellationTokenSource
            .CreateLinkedTokenSource(extraToken);
        using Operation operation = new(cts);
        // Set this as the active operation
        Operation oldOperation = Interlocked
            .Exchange(ref _activeOperation, operation);
        try
        {
            if (oldOperation is not null && !_allowConcurrency)
            {
                oldOperation.Cancel();
                // The Operation.Completion never fails.
                await oldOperation.Completion; // Continue on captured context.
            }
            cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            // Invoke the action on the initial SynchronizationContext.
            Task<TResult> task = action(cts.Token);
            return await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        finally
        {
            // If this is still the active operation, set it back to null.
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _activeOperation, null, operation);
        }
        // The operation is disposed here, along with the cts.
    }

    public Task RunAsync(Func<CancellationToken, Task> action,
        CancellationToken extraToken = default)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(action);
        return RunAsync<object>(async ct =>
        {
            await action(ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return null;
        }, extraToken);
    }

    public Task CancelAsync()
    {
        Operation operation = Volatile.Read(ref _activeOperation);
        if (operation is null) return Task.CompletedTask;
        operation.Cancel();
        return operation.Completion;
    }

    public bool Cancel() => CancelAsync().IsCompleted == false;
}
```

The primary methods of the `CancelableExecution` class are the `RunAsync` and the `Cancel`. By default concurrent (overlapping) operations are not allowed, meaning that calling `RunAsync` a second time will silently cancel and await the completion of the previous operation (if it's still running), before starting the new operation.

This class can be used in applications of any kind. Its primary intended usage though is in UI applications, inside forms with buttons for starting and canceling an asynchronous operation, or with a listbox that cancels and restarts an operation every time its selected item is changed. Here is an example of the first use-case:

```
private readonly CancelableExecution _cancelableExecution = new();

private async void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string result;
    try
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        btnExecute.Enabled = false;
        btnCancel.Enabled = true;
        result = await _cancelableExecution.RunAsync(async ct =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000, ct); // Simulate some cancelable I/O operation
            return "Hello!";
        });
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        btnExecute.Enabled = true;
        btnCancel.Enabled = false;
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
    this.Text += result;
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _cancelableExecution.Cancel();
}
```

The `RunAsync` method accepts an extra `CancellationToken` as argument, that is linked to the internally created `CancellationTokenSource`. Supplying this optional token may be useful in advanced scenarios.

For a version compatible with the .NET Framework, you can look at the [3rd revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61681938/3) of this answer.