# How do you properly dispose of a CancellationTokenSource in a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, async-await, using-statement, cancellationtokensource, disposable

Typically, when you are trying to do asynchronous tasks in a view-model, the code looks like so (simplified):

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private CancellationTokenSource CTS { get; set; }

    public async Task Process()
    {
        CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();

        try
        {
            await LongRunningTask(CTS.Token);
        } catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
    }

    public async Task Cancel()
    {
        CTS.Cancel();
    }
}
```

The problem is that `CancellationTokenSource` is an `IDisposable`. Does that mean we simply place it in a `using` block, or is there something more to it since it is stored in a private property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to dispose CancellationTokenSource?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960520/when-to-dispose-cancellationtokensource)

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you call Process multiple times and then call Cancel, you'll be cancelling the _last_ task - is that what you want? Typically you'd call Cancel on the Task returned by the method call rather than having a separate Cancel method on your VM.

Comment: Looks like `Process` should just accept a `CancellationToken` instead.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll What do you mean by *Typically you'd call Cancel on the Task returned by the method call rather than having a separate Cancel method on your VM.* `Task` doesn't have a `Cancel` method. Not sure what you mean here.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yeah just ignore me on that one, looks like we added an extension method in our local library so it's not part of the TPL library. The extension method just calls Cancel on the token source.