# Is disposing CancellationTokenSource safe when there are outstanding tokens?

Tags: .net, cancellationtokensource

If I have CancellationTokens which were previously returned by CancellationTokenSource.Token { get; } is it safe to call CancellationTokenSource Dispose()? (I'm worried that it invalidates the CancellationTokens.)

If it's not safe can I just rely on the CancellationTokenSource finalizer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not (documented to be) safe but it's also not necessary. You can store the token away and safely use it even after disposing the `CancellationTokenSource`. Just don't call `CancellationTokenSource.Token` anymore. Use the token that you obtained before disposing.

Whether you need to dispose a `CancellationTokenSource` at all is a different question. There are different cases and different opinions. There's a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960520/when-to-dispose-cancellationtokensource) about that but the answers are dubious. Use with care.