# How can I instantly return values from an async loop?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I've got an async discover function which discovers devices in the local network which I call on a button click. I'm sending a broadcast message to all devices and listen for responses for 5 seconds using a `CancellationTokenSource`. After the token has expired I'm returning an `IEnumerable` of parsed responses to my WPF model.

I'd like return incoming responses directly (and stop listening after 5 seconds) so that I can show discovered devices instantly in the UI instead of showing them all after 5 seconds.

This is my code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<IDevice>> Discover()
{
    var client = new MyClient();
    var responseData = await GetResponseData(client);
    return this.ParseResponseData(responseData);
}

private IEnumerable<IDevice> ParseResponseData(List<DeviceResponseData> responseData)
{
    foreach (var data in responseData)
    {
        yield return DeviceFactory.Create(data);
    }
}

private static async Task<List<DeviceResponseData>> GetResponseData(MyClient client,
    int timeout = 5000)
{
    var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
    var data = new List<DeviceResponseData>();

    // ... prepare message and send it
    await client.SendAsync(message, new CancellationToken());

    try
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Wait indefinitely until any message is received.
            var response = await client.ReceiveAsync(cancellationToken.Token);

            data.Add(new DeviceResponseData(/* ... */ response));
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException e)
    {

    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean return after one message, or get results as they come in?

Comment: The latter. Sending results to my UI as they come in.

Comment: I wonder do you realise just how broad a question this is. Essentially you are asking how to design an asynchronous UX. That's not just a book, it's a whole career. The short answer is _You use binding, callbacks, promises and events on a shared state model_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show results as they come in, there are many ways of achieving this, like *decoupled messages*, *events*, etc.

However, you could just use a simple `Action`

```
private static async Task<List<DeviceResponseData>> GetResponseData(MyClient client, Action<DeviceResponseData> update, int timeout = 5000)
{
   var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
   ...
   while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
      // Wait indefinitely until any message is received.
      var response = await client.ReceiveAsync(cancellationToken.Token);

      var result = new DeviceResponseData( /* ... */ response);

      data.Add(result);
      update(result);

   }
   ...
}
```

**usage**

```
var allResults =  await GetResponseData(client,data => UdpateUI(data), timeout);
```

<sub>***Note** : because this the Async Await Pattern, you wont have to marshal the result form the `Action` back to the UI Context, if that's where this was called from*</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded to C# 8, you have the option of returning an [`IAsyncEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1). This mechanism can propagate a stream of `DeviceResponseData` objects, that can be consumed as soon as they are produced. Here is the producer method, that is implemented as an [iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators) (contains `yield` statements).

```
private static async IAsyncEnumerable<DeviceResponseData> GetResponseDataStream(
    MyClient client, int timeout = 5000)
{
    using CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);

    // Prepare message...
    try
    {
        await client.SendAsync(message, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) { throw new TimeoutException(); }

    while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Response response;
        try
        {
            // Wait until any response is received.
            response = await client.ReceiveAsync(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { yield break; }

        yield return new DeviceResponseData(/* ... */ response);
    }
}
```

And here is how it can be consumed:

```
await foreach (DeviceResponseData data in GetResponseDataStream(client))
{
    // Do something with data
}
```

The best part is that you don't need to add synchronization code (`Dispatcher.Invoke` etc) every time you receive a `DeviceResponseData` object. The async/await machinery restores the captured synchronization context automatically for you (unless you tell it to do otherwise, by using the [`ConfigureAwait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskasyncenumerableextensions.configureawait) method).

**Important:** Make sure that you [dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960520/when-to-dispose-cancellationtokensource) the `CancellationTokenSource`s you create.