# Should I set a cancellation token to null after cancelling it?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code declares a cancellation token here in a view model, creates it in the OnAppearing and Cancels in the OnDisappearing:

```
public partial class DeckTabViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public CancellationTokenSource cts;
}
```

Then in OnAppearing:

```
public partial class DeckTabViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public async Task OnAppearingAsync()
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        await GetCards(cts.Token);
    }
}
```

And on Disappearing:

```
public partial class DeckTabViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public async Task OnDisappearingAsync()
    {
       cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me if this is the correct way to use the Cancellation token and should I in the OnDisappearing, also set it to null?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to dispose CancellationTokenSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960520/when-to-dispose-cancellationtokensource)

Answer (score 0):

As [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource) implements [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable), you should dispose the instance of [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource) (in your example, `cts`) when you have finished using it: you can do so directly by calling the `Dispose` method, or indirectly using the `using` construct.

In your case, you would call `Dispose` after calling `Cancel` on `cts`:

```
public partial class DeckTabViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public async Task OnDisappearingAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
        finally
        {
             if(cts != null)
             {
                 cts.Dispose();
             }
        }
    }
}
```