# Linking two CancellationTokens without redundant CancellationTokenSources

Tags: c#, .net-core, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource

Inside a method that gets an `CancellationToken` (`StartAsync`) I would like to add an internal `CancellationToken` so the asynchronous operation can either be cancelled by the caller externally or internally (e.g. by calling an `AbortAsync()` method).

AFAIK, the way to do it is to use [`CreateLinkedCancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource?view=netcore-3.1). But its APIs seems to be rather uncomfortable because I need to create **two** additional `CancellationTokenSource` instance for this and because they implement `IDisposable`, I must also not forget to dispose them. As a result, I need store both of them as members for later disposal.

Am I missing something? I feel there should be an easier way to attach an additional cancellation mechanism to an existing token that doesn't force me to maintain two `CancellationTokenSource` instances.

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken externalToken)
{
    this.actualCancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    this.linkedCancellation = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(
        actualCancellation.Token, externalToken);
    this.execution = this.ExecuteAsync(this.linkedCancellation.Token);
    return this.execution;
}

public async Task AbortAsync()
{
    try
    {
        this.actualCancellation.Cancel();
        await this.execution;
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        this.actualCancellation.Dispose();
        this.linkedCancellation.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, disposing a `CancellationTokenSource` is probably not absolutely critical. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359443/correct-pattern-to-dispose-of-cancellation-token-source/61361371#61361371) are my thoughts about this. Some people have reported [memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960520/when-to-dispose-cancellationtokensource#comment49913373_12474762) caused by undisposed CTSs, but I haven't managed to reproduce it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A linked cancellation source is not a special kind of cancellation source. It's a regular cancellation source that is also "linked" to an existing token - i.e., the source will be cancelled when the existing token is cancelled. In all other respects, it's a normal cancellation source, so you can cancel it yourself just like any other cancellation source.

So you only need one cancellation source - one that is linked to the existing token *and* can also be cancelled manually:

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken externalToken)
{
    this.linkedCancellation = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(externalToken);
    this.execution = this.ExecuteAsync(this.linkedCancellation.Token);
    return this.execution;
}

public async Task AbortAsync()
{
    try
    {
        this.linkedCancellation.Cancel();
        await this.execution;
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        this.linkedCancellation.Dipose();
    }
}
```

Just as a side note, I'd carefully consider lifetime issues with this kind of API design. Currently the `StartAsync` does resource allocation and `AbortAsync` does cleanup; I'd recommend a design where these are handled by the constructor and `Dispose` (RAII).

Comment: At once point I had my code exactly as yours and I somehow assumed that it does not work. Thanks!

Comment: The [`CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource) method has two overloads, one with two tokens as arguments and a second one with a `params` array of tokens. Surprisingly the seemingly most useful overload that would accept a single token is missing. No wonder that the misconception "at least two tokens are needed for a linked source" has been formed inside some people's minds (myself included).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Apparently they've realized this mistake and added another overload in .NET 5 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_CancellationTokenSource_CreateLinkedTokenSource_System_Threading_CancellationToken_