# How to cancel an existing task and run a new task when it completes?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I have a long running calculation that is dependant on an input value. If the input value is changed while the calculation is running, the current calculation should be canceled and a new calculation started after the previous one has completed.

The basic idea is as follows:

```
Task _latestTask = Task.CompletedTask;
CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

int Value
{
    get => _value;
    set
    {
        _value = value;
        UpdateCalculation();
    }
}

void UpdateCalculation()
{
    _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    var newTask = new Task(() => DoCalculation(Value, cancellationToken));
    _latestTask.ContinueWith(antecedent => newTask.Start(), cancellationToken);
    _latestTask = newTask;
}
```

However, I am finding that depending on how often `Value` is set, it's possible that the continuation task is cancelled before the new task is started. The whole chain of tasks stop.

How should I organize things so that the changed value causes the current calculation to be abandoned and a new calculation started once I know the previous task has completed?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `cancellationToken` from the `ContinueWith` method? Also is it guaranteed that the `Value` will be updated by a single thread, or you want the whole mechanism to be thread-safe as well?

Comment: I would just rewrite it with `await` in infinite loop... Also indeed catching exception needed for that  is a bad style...

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, this works perfectly now. Seems obvious in retrospect, thanks. It is called from the UI thread in response to a user change so doesn't need to to be thread-safe. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Can you give an infinite loop example? Not sure what you mean. I understand the point about await and exception handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could refactor your `UpdateCalculation` method in order to replace the old school `ContinueWith` with the newer async/await technology, and also to ensure that the `CancellationTokenSource` will be eventually disposed.

```
async void UpdateCalculation()
{
    _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = cts;
        var previousTask = _latestTask;
        var newTask = new Task(() => DoCalculation(Value, cts.Token), cts.Token);
        _latestTask = newTask;
        // Prevent an exception from any task to crash the application
        // It is possible that the newTask.Start() will throw too
        try { await previousTask } catch { }
        try { newTask.Start(); await newTask; } catch { }
        // Ensure that the CTS will not be canceled after is has been disposed
        if (_cancellationTokenSource == cts) _cancellationTokenSource = null;
    }
}
```

This implementation is not thread-safe. It requires that the `UpdateCalculation` will always be called from the UI thread.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.dispose#remarks) issues a strong warning about the necessity of disposing the `CancellationTokenSource`:

> Always call `Dispose` before you release your last reference to the `CancellationTokenSource`. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed until the garbage collector calls the `CancellationTokenSource` object's `Finalize` method.

Related question: [When to dispose CancellationTokenSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960520/when-to-dispose-cancellationtokensource)

Comment: I can't use a using statement here because the current calculation needs to be cancelable from elsewhere, however, I take the point about disposing of the source. Apologies for the sloppy question.

Comment: If we supply a token to the Task constructor, don't we end up with a similar problem to the one that prompted the original question? e.g. "System.InvalidOperationException: Start may not be called on a task that has completed."?

Comment: Yes, supplying a token opens the possibility for the `Task.Start` to throw. So it complicates things in your case, because you must handle this exception. On the other hand if the `DoCalculation` is not very responsive on the cancellation of the token, supplying a token in the `Task` constructor may improve the efficiency of the cancellation.

Comment: I don't want an exception on Task.Start. I want it to run and not be canceled before it is started. This is the problem I originally asked about.

Comment: @fractor I assumed that you are only interested about the task of the most recent update of the `Value` property, and the tasks of the preceding updates should either get canceled or even better don't start at all. Why is it important to start a task, if it's going to get immediately canceled anyway? Btw in retrospect your initial code with `ContinueWith` looks OK as is, and should not cause the whole chain of tasks to stop. Are you sure that you use the UI thread everywhere? Check if you have other `ContinueWith` elsewhere, because their actions are running on `ThreadPool` threads.

Comment: The previous tasks should get canceled, but they must not be canceled before they are started since the subsequent attempt to start a canceled task throws an exception.
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); var t = new Task(() => { }, cts.Token); cts.Cancel(); t.Start(); // Throws InvalidOperationException

Comment: @fractor yes, but what's the problem with this exception? It's not stopping the chain of tasks in your original code. It is called from a fire-and-forget continuation. Unless you are calling `Start` from elsewhere too.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. I'm left wondering why removing the cancellation token from the call to ContinueWith resolved my issue.

Comment: I also see that _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel can be called elsewhere since Dispose won't be called until the new task has completed. Thanks.

Comment: I do find `System.InvalidOperationException: Start may not be called on a task that has completed.` uncomfortable though.

Comment: @fractor I agree about being uncomfortable. TBH I was unaware of this behavior until I wrote this answer. :-)