# Reliable delayed execution class in C#

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, delay, execution

To control delays between animations in an iOS game I've developed I have written this "Delayer" class below. But I'm experiencing some rare random crashes possible related to objects being deallocated:

```
0x102933344 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/52DE96A6-70CF-4D3D-A6F0-3DDAB4F31347/DiscDrop.iOS.app/DiscDrop.iOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info
0x1029295b0 - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/52DE96A6-70CF-4D3D-A6F0-3DDAB4F31347/DiscDrop.iOS.app/DiscDrop.iOS : mono_handle_native_crash
0x10293776c - /var/containers/Bundle/Application/52DE96A6-70CF-4D3D-A6F0-3DDAB4F31347/DiscDrop.iOS.app/DiscDrop.iOS : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler_debug
0x1dd9f69fc - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>
0x1dcfd9b9c - /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib : <redacted>
0x1dcfd9b9c - /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib : <redacted>
0x1dddf7bb0 - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : _CFAutoreleasePoolPop
0x1de871744 - /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation : <redacted>
```

so I am wondering if anyone can spot a problem with the class:

```
public class Delayer
{
    private readonly List<CancellationTokenSource> cancellationTokenSources;

    public Delayer()
    {
        this.cancellationTokenSources = new List<CancellationTokenSource>();
    }

    public void DelayedCall(float delay, Action callback)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        this.cancellationTokenSources.Add(cancellationTokenSource);
        _ = Delayer.CallbackAfterDelay(delay, cancellationTokenSource, delegate
        {
            this.cancellationTokenSources.Remove(cancellationTokenSource);
            callback?.Invoke();
        });
    }

    public void CancelAll()
    {
        foreach (CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource in this.cancellationTokenSources)
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();   // cancellationTokenSource.Dispose(); here doesnt help leak
        }
        this.cancellationTokenSources.Clear();
    }

    private static async Task CallbackAfterDelay(float delay, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource, Action callback)
    {
        await Task.Delay((int)(delay * 1000), cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            callback?.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("### Common.Delayer.DelayedCall caught exception={0}", exception.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example of how I use it:

```
this.delayer = new Delayer();
//...
this.delayer.DelayedCall(delay: 0.5f, callback: delegate
{
    this.PlaySound(duration: 0.2f);
}
```

Comment: Note also that your class is not thread safe, and I'm taking a guess here that (based on the design) you intend to call methods on this class concurrently. If that's the case, adding and removing from the list is not safe without a locking mechanism

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 the OP is probably intending to use this class in a GUI application with a `SynchronizationContext` installed. In that case the `SynchronizationContext` will take care of synchronizing all asynchronous continuations, by invoking them on the UI thread. Otherwise things would be much more complex. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960520/when-to-dispose-cancellationtokensource/61681938#61681938) a thread-safe `CancelableExecution` class, and how much code I had to write in order to make it work correctly.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'm talking about access to the `cancellationTokenSources` list. A SyncContext isnt going to synchronize access to that field. If two Adds or an Add/remove happen simultaneously bad things can happen. Better to use a lock around access or a concurrent collection. Just saying

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 how is it possible for two simultaneous Adds (or an Add/remove) to occur, if all code paths are going to run on the same thread?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias that's assuming they are. Back to my original comment was "*if*" they had concurrent access to be careful. Not that they *do*

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 well, lets wait for the OP to clarify whether the `Delayer` class is supposed to be thread-safe or not.

Comment: Delayer is absolutely only ever intended to be called on the main UI thread, so no need to worry about concurrent access. I should have mentioned that in the question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The `_ = Delayer.CallbackAfterDelay` task is launched in a fire-and-forget fashion, so you won't be notified in case there are any bugs in your implementation. And I can see a bug already: `await`ing the `Task.Delay` may result to an `OperationCanceledException` which is not caught, so in this case the `callback?.Invoke();` will not be invoked, resulting to the associated `cancellationTokenSource` not being removed from the list.

The easiest way to ensure that all exceptions will be surfaced is to convert the `CallbackAfterDelay` from `async Task` to [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). This change will force you to be *very* careful with how you code things, because any non-caught exception inside this method will be unhandled (not simply unobserved), and will crash the process.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What causes OperationCanceledException? Do you mean when cancellationTokenSource.Cancel() is called? I think that's the only way it can happen. In which case I don't want the callback to be called (I want CancelAll to stop any pending callbacks). And yes I am missing exceptions being caught so would be good to fix that.

Comment: @Bbx yes, the task returned by `Task.Delay` may complete in a [`Canceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus) state, in case the supplied `CancellationToken` is canceled before the task's completion. And when awaiting canceled tasks, an `OperationCanceledException` is thrown.