# CancellationTokenSource for changing state after few seconds

Tags: c#, async-await, task, .net-6.0

I'm trying to recreate the effect one sees in Outlook / Gmail: a few seconds after opening an unread email, it is marked as read. But if one clicks a different email before that time elapses then the email remains unread.

```cs
private CancellationTokenSource? _cts;

private async Task OnEmailClicked(int id)
{

  if (_cts != null)
  {
    _cts.Cancel();                                // I suspect problem is here
    _cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();    // or here
    _cts.Dispose();
    _cts = null;
  }

  await LoadEmail(id);

  try
  {
    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    await Task.Delay(3000, _cts.Token);
  }
  catch (TaskCanceledException)
  {
    return;
  }
  finally {
    _cts.Dispose();
    _cts = null;
  }

  await MarkEmailAsRead(id);
}
```

That gives me weird results. Sometimes it works and sometimes not. I'm unsure where/how to create, cancel and dispose the token source. Obviously my code is wrong.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

(I don't need to "fix" this code - I'm happy to throw it away and do it the proper way, if you can show me how. I've only included it to demonstrate what I've tried.)

Comment: What do you mean by "first time"? It only works for the first email you open and not for any other? Also, what do you mean by "the UI doesn't update properly"?

Comment: *"when I click another email (and another, to trigger the cancellation) it no longer works, all emails remain in their original state"* - Don't you want them to remain in their original state (unread) if the cancellation is triggered?

Comment: Sorry you are right, that's not what I meant. Like I said it's hard to explain without talking about UI, which will just complicate things. Basically, it doesn't work. :-) Sometimes the delay effect works, sometimes not, and sometimes it works but incorrectly. I am very sure my code is **completely wrong**. I would like to throw it away and use a better way, from someone who understands this better than me.

Comment: What class is this code in? Does each email create a new instance of the class that this is in?

Comment: No it's single blazor component. I imagine the same problem would exist if I used this code for a terminal email programme. I know the async / cancellationtoken is the issue, because I've not done this before - I'm sure I'm not creating, cancelling and disposing in the correct order.

Comment: I don't think you should be using a mutable field to store the `CancellationTokenSource`.

Comment: @Dai Yes I wondered about that. I wasn't sure how else to do it, I need to keep a reference to the "old" token source so I can cancel it,

Comment: By the way, `TaskCanceledException` inherits from `OperationCanceledException`, so if you catch the latter you handle both.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel While that's true, it won't matter here since the [documentation for `Task.Delay()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-task-delay(system-int32-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) says that it throws a `TaskCanceledException`. But that is useful knowledge to have nonetheless.

Comment: He wrote that in response to my older comment asking whether to catch it - which I asked because the docs for `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` say that it is thrown. So I wasn't sure. In your design below, you've removed that bit, so it's much simpler now. BTW thanks Etienne for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, calling `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` will break things. It will throw an exception every time that line is hit (because you just cancelled the token the line before) and the rest of the method won't run.

The other issue I see is that you're setting `_cts` to null after cancelling it. Remember that you will have two versions of this method in progress at the same time. Assuming both versions of the method will be running on the UI thread then this entire block of code will run uninterrupted (I've removed `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`):

```
  if (_cts != null)
  {
    _cts.Cancel();
    _cts.Dispose();
    _cts = null;
  }
```

And then once `LoadEmail(id)` is awaited, then the previous incomplete version of the method is given a chance to run and it goes into the `catch` and the `finally` where it calls `_cts.Dispose()`. But `_cts` has already been set to `null` so you will get a `NullReferenceException` and `MarkEmailAsRead(id)` will never get run.

So I would only call `Dispose()` in one place, not two. But I would also keep a reference to the `CancellationTokenSource` that we created so that if something new is assigned to `_cts`, we can still call `Dispose()` on the one we created. That would look something like this:

```
private CancellationTokenSource? _cts;

private async Task OnEmailClicked(int id)
{
  
  _cts?.Cancel();

  // Keep a local reference to the token source so that we can still call Dispose()
  // on the object we created here even if _cts gets assigned a new object by another
  // run of this method
  var cts = _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  
  await LoadEmail(id);
  
  try
  {
    await Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token);
  }
  catch (TaskCanceledException)
  {
    return;
  }
  finally {
    // Only assign _cts = null if another run hasn't already assigned
    // a new token
    if (cts == _cts) _cts = null;
    cts.Dispose();
  }

  await MarkEmailAsRead(id);
}
```

I didn't test this, but see if it fulfills your requirements.

If the use of `cts` vs `_cts` looks confusing to you, it may help to read up on [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). But the important part is that assigning a new instance to `_cts` doesn't destroy the object that it used to refer to, and any other part of the code that still has a reference to that object can still use it.

If you've never seen the `?.` before, it's the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, it will take me a little while to digest all this good info and test it. I'll post back here soon, thanks!

Comment: I just edited it to move the creation of the `CancellationTokenSource` to before the call to `LoadEmail(id)`. I'm just thinking that if several emails are opened in very quick succession, it's possible that one of the cancellation tokens won't get cancelled (because you don't know which other task will run while awaiting `LoadEmail(id)`.

Comment: Just tried it, and it works like a charm! Thanks not only for fixing my code, but explaining why it was failing, I've learnt a lot from this.

Comment: FWIW I don't like suppressing `ObjectDisposedException`s. This exception is thrown to inform us that we did something wrong: we tried to use a disposable object that has already been disposed. We are not supposed to do that. Instead of hiding the evidence of the abuse under the carpet, the correct reaction is to fix the code, so that the disposable object is never touched again after its disposal.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I don't like catching exceptions when they can be avoided either, but I didn't see any way around it in this case. You don't want to set `_cts` to `null` since there is the chance that several emails are opened in very quick succession, which means there could be more than 2 version of this method being in progress at any given time and the second iteration could be dereferencing the instance that the third run created, for example. But since you're not setting `_cts` to `null` and there is no way to check if it's already disposed, this is the only way I saw.

Comment: Gabriel you can set it to `null` before disposing it, under the condition that the field is equal to the local variable: `if (cts == _cts) _cts = null;` Are you seeing any problem with that?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I was going to say what if `cts != _cts`, but I guess that would only happen if another run happens and then there's no point tracking it in the field anymore and you don't lose anything. So yeah, I guess that works.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you're essentially restarting a watchdog timer for three seconds every time you click a different email. If the WDT expires without getting a new click then you go ahead and mark the latest email as 'Read'.

For years, I used (successfully) this same approach to cancel the old task when starting a new one for the WDT. But then I realized I could just do this:

```
int _wdtCount = 0;
// Returning 'void' to emphasize that this should 'not' be awaited!
async void onEmailClicked(int id)
{
    _wdtCount++;
    var capturedCount = _wdtCount;
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));   
    // If the 'captured' localCount has not changed after waiting 3 seconds
    // it indicates that no new selections have been made in that time.        
    if(capturedCount.Equals(_wdtCount))
    {
        await MarkEmailAsRead(id);
    }
}

async Task MarkEmailAsRead(int id)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"The email with the ID '{id}' has been marked read");
}
```

Anyway, works for me and it's just a thought...

**TESTBENCH**

```
#region T E S T
onEmailClicked(id: 1);
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));


onEmailClicked(id: 2);
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));


onEmailClicked(id: 3);
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));


onEmailClicked(id: 10);
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));


onEmailClicked(id: 20);
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));


onEmailClicked(id: 30);
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
#endregion T E S T
```

[image: console]

---

**EDIT**

*Though I realize that the post no longer has the wording entertaining 'other' options than task cancellation, I still wanted to incorporate the excellent comments and improve my original answer by putting the `WatchDogTimer` in a class...*

```
class WatchDogTimer
{
    int _wdtCount = 0;
    public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    public void ThrowBone(Action action)
    {
        _wdtCount++;
        var capturedCount = _wdtCount;
        Task
            .Delay(Interval)
            .GetAwaiter()
            .OnCompleted(() =>
            {                    
                // If the 'captured' localCount has not changed after 
                // awaiting the Interval, it indicates that no new
                // 'bones' have been thrown during that interval.    
                if (capturedCount.Equals(_wdtCount))
                {
                    action();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

*... and eliminating the `async void` from the posit.*

```
void onEmailClicked(int id)
    => _watchDog.ThrowBone(() => MarkEmailAsRead(id));

void MarkEmailAsRead(int id)
{
    // BeginInvoke(()=>
    // {
    Console.WriteLine($"Expired: {_stopWatch.Elapsed}");
    Console.WriteLine($"The email with the ID '{id}' has been marked read");
    // });
}
```

**TESTBENCH**

```
#region T E S T
// Same test parameters as before.
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch _stopWatch = 
    new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
WatchDogTimer _watchDog = 
    new WatchDogTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3) };

_stopWatch.Start();
Console.WriteLine(_stopWatch.Elapsed);
onEmailClicked(id: 1);
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));


Console.WriteLine(_stopWatch.Elapsed);
onEmailClicked(id: 2);
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));


Console.WriteLine(_stopWatch.Elapsed);
onEmailClicked(id: 3);
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));


Console.WriteLine(_stopWatch.Elapsed);
onEmailClicked(id: 10);
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));


Console.WriteLine(_stopWatch.Elapsed);
onEmailClicked(id: 20);
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));


Console.WriteLine(_stopWatch.Elapsed);
onEmailClicked(id: 30);
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
#endregion T E S T
```

[image: screenshot with elapsed]

Comment: `async void` <-- Please don't do this.

Comment: This is clever! (async void aside) I was going to say that you run the (very small) risk of running into `int.MaxValue` and an exception, but that doesn't happen - it just wraps around to `int.MinValue`

Comment: This is a very clever design, thanks IV!

Comment: @Gabriel Luci this is why I indicated in the comment _why_ I marked it as such :) So why did I change it to `void` in the first place? Because in my testbench I at first inadvertently awaited it even though I wrote it and knew the correct call would be `_= onEmailClicked(int id)`. So this is just to keep a user from awaiting it. It won't work if it's awaited and if _I_ can make the mistake then anyone could ;)

Comment: If it's an event (which is entirely plausible) then yeah, `async void` is the only way, but the code in the question is `async Task` so presumably that `Task` is being tracked somewhere (even if it's not immediately awaited).

Comment: What this is missing, is a method called `KickTheDog()`, just because that would be awesome.

Comment: @Ionix are you thinking what I'm thinking? Wouldn't it be even _more_ awesome to _use_ your method in a brand new _game_ called [KikTheDog](https://github.com/IVSoftware/watch-dog-timer-game).

Comment: FYI Although the accepted answer is related to the question directly and uses a cancellation token approach, I ended up using this design. Very simple and elegant.

Comment: Imagine if all SO answers could be answered in the format of short playable games. Such a world would be most awesome.

Comment: [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IVSoftware.Portable.WatchdogTimer)

Answer (score 1):

First, I am assuming that your code is single-threaded. The [`CancellationTokenSource.Dispose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.dispose) method is not thread-safe, so trying to dispose `CancellationTokenSource`s that are shared in a multithreaded environment is [a small nightmare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960520/when-to-dispose-cancellationtokensource/61681938#61681938). You could check that your code is single-threaded, by searching for `Task.Run` and `.ConfigureAwait(false)` in the code that interacts with the `CancellationTokenSource`s. If you find any, you might be in trouble.

Second, you should be aware that the [`CancellationTokenSource.Cancel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel) method is "jumpy". It immediately invokes all the callbacks that have been registred previously via the [`CancellationToken.Register`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register) route. Code like `await Task.Delay(3000, _cts.Token);` implicitly registers a callback, so it is possible that the execution flow will jump to the code after the `await` before continuing with the code after the `Cancel`. Your code should be prepared for such jumps. You shouldn't assume that the `Cancel` will complete quickly, nor that it won't throw. In case a registered callback fails, the exception will be surfaced by the `Cancel` call.

As for the specifics of your code, your mistake is that you interact with the `_cts` field too much. You should reduce the interactions to the minimum. You should also assume that after an `await` the `_cts` will not store the same instance that you assigned before the `await`. Your code is single-threaded, but asynchronous. Asynchronous code has a complex execution flow. I agree with Gabriel Luci that you should `Dispose` in one place only. Using `async void` is not that bad, since it's normal for UI event handlers to be `async void`. It might bite you when you are done with the application and attempt to close the Window, because you will have no way to wait for the completion of the pending async operations before closing. So you might get annoying errors after closing the Window, because the async operations will try to interact with UI components that have been disposed. Ideally you should store a reference of the latest asynchronous operation (the `Task`), and await it before starting the next operation, or before closing the Window. But for the purpose of keeping the answer simple I will omit this complexity. Here is my suggestion:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

private async void OnEmailClicked(int id)
{
    _cts?.Cancel();

    CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
    try
    {
        _cts = cts;
        await LoadEmail(id);
        try { await Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token); }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { return; } // Do nothing
    }
    finally
    {
        if (cts == _cts) _cts = null;
        cts.Dispose();
    }
    await MarkEmailAsRead(id);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the additional important details. I eventually used the solution by @IVSoftware to avoid the async issues completely, but I first used your and Gabriel's way and I can confirm it works as expected. I assume some people will need to do it that way, so it's good to have this here. Thanks!