# Wrapping a task in an async with a timeout?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, task-parallel-library, f#-async

I would like to run a function in a background thread, then consume the result with a timeout from an `async` context.

Here is my code:

```ml
open System.Threading.Tasks

let forever () =
  while true do
    ()
  123

async {
  printfn "Computing..."

  let! ct = Async.CancellationToken

  let! c =
    Task.Run(forever, ct)
    |> Async.AwaitTask
    |> fun t -> Async.StartChild(t, millisecondsTimeout = 1_000)

  let! x = c

  printfn $"%i{x}"
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

I would expect this to raise an exception after 1 second, but it hangs forever.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're waiting on a forever loop.

Comment: @JimFoye Is there a way to wrap that with a timeout though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells of https://xyproblem.info hence I'd suggest posting a followup that is more representative of your overall needs (i.e. to what degree are you mixing Task and Async in your real problem; are you trying to make a general helper, or just trying to understand things)

`async` expressions check for cancellation of the ambient CT at wait points (i.e. a `let!` etc). `task` expressions (and Task stuff in general) has no such semantics

- your `forever` cannot be cancelled in any meaningful way as it is written as

  - you did not pass it a `CancellationToken`
  - you are hence not checking/able to check for a `.IsCancellationTokenRequested` to trigger the end of the loop

---

If you'll allow some soapboxing, the high level conclusion of all this is:

1. if you opt to do `task` stuff ANYWHERE, you should flow cancellation tokens to make yourself think and consider all the cases
2. and that makes business level code horrendous
3. So all **app** code should be `async {`, with brief call-outs to Task stuff as required, but *always* passing a CT
4. People who say "oh great F# has `task` in the box now, we no longer need to pay the allocation and slight perf rax of `Async` are very mistaken - you can't afford for `task` to leak into your code. If the `async {` Builder ever gets rewritten to take advantage of the resumable state machine mechanisms that `task` uses, then the overhead drops more. Some of that future is already being explored in https://github.com/TheAngryByrd/IcedTasks etc

---

You have multiple style issues in your snippet which don't make it easy to five a succinct answer:

- piping Async.AwaitTask and Async.StartChild makes things very confusing. Don't do that. If you stop doing that, it will be even more obvious what's wrong (you are starting the task and waiting for it to complete before any StartChild could possibly enter the picture)
- cancellation in Async etc (but also Task) is 100% co-operative (and I don't see you clearly communicating you get that point), and the in the box stuff never abandons a wait on a task or async execution (except things like `Async.StartAsTask` etc. Highly recommend multiple reads of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/async

---

Helper for doing this inside a `task` expr:

```ml
/// Runs an inner task with a dedicated Linked Token Source. Cancels via the ct upon completion, before Disposing the LCTS
let inline runWithCancellation (ct: CancellationToken) ([<InlineIfLambda>]f: CancellationToken -> Task) = task {
    use cts = System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct) // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960520/when-to-dispose-cancellationtokensource
    try do! f cts.Token
    finally cts.Cancel() }
```

It's [consumed in the Propulsion project in various ways](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ajet%2Fpropulsion%20runWithCancellation&type=code)

---

An alternate approach (closer to what you're trying) is something like: [(source)](https://github.com/jet/propulsion/blob/104b3bec1c2f0ee302ee0266dc6e0ec901ba2e27/src/Propulsion.MemoryStore/ReactorInternal.fs#L9)

```ml
module Async =

    /// Wraps a computation, cancelling (and triggering a timeout exception) if it doesn't complete within the specified timeout
    let timeoutAfter (timeout: TimeSpan) (c: Async<'a>) = async {
        let! r = Async.StartChild(c, millisecondsTimeout = int timeout.TotalMilliseconds)
        return! r }
```

Comment: Yes, my misunderstanding was that I thought a running task could be halted non-cooperatively.

Comment: cool - also added a soapbox section just here. I'm absolutely convinced based on painful experience that sticking to `async {` is definitely for the best in app code, and I didn't want to leave anyone with the impression that messy/complex task juggling like I linked to shold be a day to day thing; ToIRL I use the [`Async.call`](https://github.com/jet/propulsion/blob/104b3bec1c2f0ee302ee0266dc6e0ec901ba2e27/src/Propulsion/Internal.fs#L128) as the only helper to call out to Task stuff as a) it flows cancellation b) it does `AwaitTaskCorrect` unwrapping/correct cancellation

Comment: I totally agree - `async` is the best default choice.